# Strtok not working properly reading a string with multiple lines

Tags: c, lex, strtok

So, I'm using a lexer to and after all the flex shenanigans I get this text:

```
ISEP 1252 "ADDRESS"
"Name1" 1253 "INFORMATICA"
"Name2" 1254 "Boilerplate1"
"Name3" 1255 "Boilerplate2"
"Name4" 1256 "Boilerplate3"
"Name5" 1257 "Boilerplate4"
"Name6" 1258 "Boilerplate5"
```

and its stored in `yytext`, then im proceding to separate each line and the contents of the line using `strtok`:

```
// get first line
char* line = strtok(yytext, "\n");
// get school name
char* schoolName = strtok(line, " \t");
// get school num students
int schoolNumStudents = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \t"));
// get school address inside the quotes
char* schoolAddress = strtok(NULL, "\"");

strcpy(schools[schoolCount].name, schoolName);
schools[schoolCount].numStudents = schoolNumStudents;
strcpy(schools[schoolCount].address, schoolAddress);
//print school[schoolCount]
printf("Escola: %s\n", schools[schoolCount].name);
printf("Num alunos: %d\n", schools[schoolCount].numStudents);
printf("Morada: %s\n", schools[schoolCount].address);

// get teachers
line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
while (line != NULL) {
    char* teacherName = strtok(line, "\"");
    int teacherExt = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \t"));
    char* teacherDepartment = strtok(NULL, "\"");

    schools[schoolCount].numTeachers++;
    if(schools[schoolCount].teachers == NULL) {
        schools[schoolCount].teachers = (struct Teacher*) malloc(sizeof(struct Teacher));
    }
    else {
        schools[schoolCount].teachers = (struct Teacher*) realloc(schools[schoolCount].teachers, sizeof(struct Teacher) * (schools[schoolCount].numTeachers));
    }

    printf("Nome: %s\n", teacherName);
    printf("Ext: %d\n", teacherExt);
    printf("Departamento: %s\n", teacherDepartment);
    line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}

schoolCount++;
```

the thing to see here is that, being `yytext` the string I provided, the second `strtok(NULL, "\n")` returns `NULL` instead of the second line. Is there something I'm missing?

PS: there is nothing beside the code I provided related to C, the code block is nested inside a lex rule.

I tried copying the contents of yytext to a different variable since strtok alters the variable and yytext is reserved to lex, that didn't accomplish anything, I tried clearing the strtok buffer and retrying the strtok in the second line onwards, also didn't work.

Comment: You can't alternate `strtok()` between different strings, because it keeps static state related to the current string, and it modifies the string in place. Use `strtok_r()` so you can keep separate state for each string you're parsing.

Comment: Why are you using a lexer **and** `strtok`? The lexer will have much more detailed and fast string extraction techniques available.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after calling `strtok` for the substring line

```
char* line = strtok(yytext, "\n");
// get school name
char* schoolName = strtok(line, " \t");
//..
```

the function `strtok` keeps a pointer inside the array `line`. So the next call of `strtok`

```
line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

refers to `line` instead of `yytext`.

One approach to avoid the problem is to calculate the length of the
string stored in `line` like for example

```
char *pos = yytext;

char* line = strtok( pos, "\n");
size_t n = strlen( line );
//...
```

and to use the value as an offset within the array `yytext` for the next call of `strtok` for the array `yytext`

```
pos += n;
line = strtok( pos, "\n");
//...
```